# Power BI Format pane

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am learning Power BI, I couldn't able to find this Format tab to change the selection of option in Slicer visualization.

[Slicer that I want to change:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d73Y4.png)

Setting that I am lookinig for Format -> Slicer Settings -> options -> Style

[My dashboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHThI.png)

I tried to find the slicer settings by searching on top, but nothing appeared, after selecting slicer I saw a format button on top, but it doesn't have slicer settings.